# How to pass a textbox value to another jsp page via href

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to pass a data that has been entered in a text box

Source page : page1.jsp  Target page : page2.jsp

page1.jsp code

```
<input type="text" id="date" autocomplete="off" >
<br>
<button onclick='window.top.location.href ="page2.jsp?id=document.getElementByID('date').value">


onclick='window.top.location.href ="flush.jsp?id="document.getElementById('datepicker').value"'>
```

in what way can i pass the value entered in the text box through via href attribute ??

Comment: What happened when you execute the above code ? have you tried anything?

Comment: no value is getting passed..IF enter static value its getting passed to the target page.

Comment: you have to use document.getElementById('date').value.. refer this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementbyid

Comment: yeah i used that only.. i forgot to mention in the code have edited it now

Comment: onclick='window.top.location.href ="flush.jsp?id="document.getElementById('datepicker').value"'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate the string in javascript. I think you have mix up javascript code with JSP script i.e. page2.jsp?id=<%=date%> (this is JSP scripting)

```
<button onclick='window.top.location.href="page2.jsp?id=" + document.getElementById("date").value;'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I fix the document.getElementByID('date') to document.getElementId("date"). It should work now. You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/53HAb/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this--

```
<input type="text" id="date" autocomplete="off" value='ABC'/>
    <br>
        <button onclick='window.location ="page2.jsp?d="+document.getElementById("date").value'>Click me </button>
```

Heres the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/PMc4E/1/)